# Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast) enum

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder

I have copied the variable data from enum type which is declared outside the structure to the enum type variable which is written inside structure but it is throwing building error as Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)

```
enum TGenObjType                        //sundar
{
   TYPE_UNDEFINED 
   , TYPE_CAR      
    , TYPE_TRUCK     
    , TYPE_MOTORBIKE 
   , TYPE_BIKE      
  , TYPE_PEDESTRIAN
  };

struct SGenObjData
{
  enum TGenObjType                recogType                          ; /* #RTAS: input               */ /* Object type (vehicle, pedestrian, ...)                                      */
  enum TGenObjType                commuType                          ; /* #RTAS: input               */ /* Object type (vehicle, pedestrian, ...)                                      */
}; 


 ushort j(0);
   for (ulong i = 0; i < gol.mData.size(); ++i)
 {
   if (gol.mData[i].isValid > 0)
    {
     if (gol.mData[i].id <= OBJ_MAX_ID)
     {
        objectList.objectIdx[size_t(gol.mData[i].id)][size_t(SRC_LIST1)]           = ushort(j);

             switch (gol.mData[i].recognized_shape)
            {
            case EO_SHAPE_CAR       : objectList.objects[j].recogType =    TYPE_CAR           ; break;
            case EO_SHAPE_TRUCK     : objectList.objects[j].recogType = TYPE_TRUCK         ; break;
            case EO_SHAPE_MOTORBIKE : objectList.objects[j].recogType = TYPE_MOTORBIKE ; break;
           case EO_SHAPE_BIKE      : objectList.objects[j].recogType = TYPE_BIKE      ; break;
           case EO_SHAPE_PEDESTRIAN: objectList.objects[j].recogType = TYPE_PEDESTRIAN; break;
            case EO_SHAPE_UNDEFINED :                                                                  
            default                 :    myDataLst.objectList.objects[j].recogType =    TYPE_UNDEFINED ;
         }// throwing an error Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
```

can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78548/discussion-on-question-by-meenakshy-sundaresan-conversion-to-enumeration-type-re).

Answer (score 2):

A named `enum` is a distinct type. it has an underlying type and a "weak" `enum` allows implicit conversion *to* the underlying type. It does not support implicit conversion from the underlying type to the `enum`. An `enum` declared with the same name as another `enum` but in a different scopr is a distinct type of its own (this applies to all types). Since the `enum` does not support implicitly conversion *from* the underlying type you cannot simply assign the value of one `enum` to another, even if the `enum`'s and all of their members have identical names and values.

```
enum Foo
{
    Bar = 0
};
```

is not the same as

```
struct Object
{
    enum Foo
    {
        Bar = 0
    };
};
```

Both `Foo` and `Object::Foo` are distinct types and C++ does not allow implicitly conversion between them.

```
Object:Foo innerFoo = Bar; // Error Bar and Object::Bar are not the same

Object:Foo innerFoo = Onject::Bar; // OK! They are the same!
```

It sounds like the two `enum`'s are redundant so you need to decide which version of `TGenObjType` you want to use and delete the other.

Comment: So what I want to do now to correct that error in my code ??
can you guide me for that?

Comment: Actually enum TGenObjType is for TYPE_CAR
and enum TObjType recogtype which is inside the structure, as you said there is no 2 times  TGenObjType to delete one.

Comment: The only additional advice I can give you is to update your question with the relevant code (preferably an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and more context on what you're trying to accomplish (not just code). Right now we don't know if you need to do a simple conversion, remove a redundant `enum`, or if what you're trying to do is flawed form the start.

Comment: enum TObjType          recoType                          ;
     enum TGenObjType TYPE_CAR ; 

     recoType = TYPE_CAR;

how can we assign the value from enum type TGenObjType to TObjType, Can you answer for this question??
if so thats my answer

Comment: Thanks guys, it was a small mistake by myself. both i have declare with same enum name.. I got that...